# Installing Indy10 into C++ Builder6. showing Indysystem60.bpl is not found.

Tags: indy

I am having a problem installing Indy10 into C++ Builder6.
Everything goes to great when installing the package and the components
display in the Indy tabs
but after closing and restarting BCB get the following messages
"This application has failed to start because IndySystem60.bpl was not
found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem"
After clicking OK I get
"Can't load package C:\Indy\Indy10\C6\dclIndyCore60.bpl.
The specified module could not be found."

I get the same messages for the IndyProtocols60.bpl

Once BCB starts all the Indy Tabs are gone and in Component Install Packages
the Design packages
Indy 10 Core Design Time and
Indy 10 Protocols Design Time are unchecked.
The Path is added to the Tools || Environment Options || Library Path

One thing I do note is in the C6 directory there is 2 design time files

dclIndyCore60.bpl and dclIndyProtocols60.bpl

but there are 3 runtime files

IndyCore60.bpl, IndyProtocols60.bpl and IndySystem60.bpl

Removing and adding them again brings them back but restarting BCB it all
starts again.

What am I doing wrong that is causing these to not be found when BCB starts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BPL files are not located in a folder that is on the IDE's BPL search path, that is why it cannot find them when the IDE is restarted.  Either move the files or change the search path. The `Library Path` is not the correct search path for BPL files, it is for OBJ and non-Package LIB files instead. Use the `BPL output dir` search path instead for BPL files. Also, if you compiled BPI/LIB files for the Packages, use the `BPI/LIB output dir` search path for them.

And yes, there are 2 design-time packages but 3 run-time packages.  The `IndySystem` package does not register any design-time pieces.